# What does it mean when the Negative Log-Likelihood returns infinity?

Tags: r, likelihood

I am using the package `mvtnorm` and using `dmvnorm` to calculate the negative log likelihood in R by doing `-sum(dmvnorm(x= data , mean = mu, sigma = sigma, log = TRUE)`

For different parameters, it sometimes returns $\infty$, and I am not sure what this means intuitively. Am I calculating NLL correctly?

Comment: I wonder if this happened because `sigma` is non-positive?

Comment: @Sycorax I didn’t have the opportunity to try it now, but wouldn’t it produce NaN’s in that case, due to logarithm of negative number?

Comment: @gunes depends on how the optimization code is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means your log-likelihood is $-\infty$, and your likelihood is $0$. The likelihood is $$\prod f(x_i;\mu,\sigma)$$ 
In order for it to be $0$, at least one of the multiplicands must be $0$. Theoretically, it’s not possible because normal pdf is non-zero everywhere. But, since computers use finite precision arithmetics, it seems some data values are so odd/unlikely that your PDF returns $0$.

**Edit:** @Sycorax, I had a chance to try the library. Interestingly, `Inf` can be produced both ways:

- Highy unlikely samples:

  ```
  library(mvtnorm)    
  -sum(dmvnorm(rep(c(1),10000), log=TRUE))
  ```
- As well as a negative sigma (or non positive semidefinite covariance):

  ```
  sigma <- matrix(c(-4), ncol=1)
  -sum(dmvnorm(rep(c(1),1), sigma=sigma, log=TRUE))
  ```

@hkj447 : I've found another library [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/emdbook/versions/1.3.11/topics/dmvnorm), which seems to raise an exception when the covariance matrix is invalid, as well as doesn't produce `Inf` as easy as yours.